# awk function printing..... -bash?

Tags: bash, awk

For some reason that i'm trying to figure out i'm getting "-bash" printed out of this script:

```
cat sample | awk -v al=$0 -F"|" '{n = split(al, a, "|")} {print a[1]}'
```

the 'sample' file contains psv "pipe separated value", like a|b|c|d|e|f|d.
My intention is to use an array.
The result of the above script is an array of length 1 and th only item contained is "-bash", the name of the shell.
$0 by default points to the program that is currently used, but as far as i know, within an awk script, the $0 parameter 'should' point to the entire line being read.

since i would like to understand where the problem exaclty is "i'm new to bash/awk"
can you point me out which of the following steps is failing?
1-"concatenate" the sample file and pass it as input for the awk script
2-define a variable named 'al' with as value each line contained in 'sample'
3-define a pipe "|" as field separator
4-define an action, split the value of 'al' into an array named 'a' using a pipe as splitter
5-define another action, which in this case is simply printing the first item in the array

Any advice? thank you!

Comment: Please, don't use `cat`, it is unnecessary - `awk` takes a filename as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The `$0` is expanded by the shell before it runs `awk`, and `$0` is the name of the current program, which is `bash`, the `-` at the start is because bash was run by *login(1)* (see the description of the `exec` builtin in `man bash`)

You need to quote the `$0` so the shell doesn't expand it, and awk sees it:

```
awk -v 'al=$0' -F"|" '{n = split(al, a, "|")} {print a[1]}' sample
```

But variable assignments are processed *before* reading any data, so that sets the variable `al` to the string "$0" at the start of the program, it does *not* set `al` to the contents of each input record.

If you want the record, just say so instead of using a variable:

```
awk -F"|" '{n = split($0, a, "|")} {print a[1]}' sample
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, the second version you have wrote works perfectly thank you, but the first one, the one that is assigning a variable **'al=$0'** still has some issue, the assignment **'al=$0'** gives the variable 'al' the value of '$0' (literally). the array will have size 1 and'$0' in a[1],

Comment: Yes, that's what I told you in my answer, did you read it?  _"so that sets the variable `al` to the string "$0" at the start of the program"_

Answer (score 1):

By `-v a1=$0`, you are setting `a1` to the name of the current programme, which is bash. See *Arguments* in [man bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

Comment: huh?? i thought it would read the data provided by **cat sample |**

Comment: $0 by default points to the program that is currently used, but as far as i know, within an awk script, the $0 parameter 'should' point to the entire line being read.

Comment: I am not sure about `awk`, but `$0` appears outside of the awk script, so it gets interpreted by the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Err...

```
awk -F'|' '{ print $1 }' sample
```

Comment: is using the split function, which gives an array, the fact that the array its used within a simple print action is purely for testing purposes, i have added this in the first question.